# How can I use SELECT INTO in PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I was trying to code something like this using PDO

```
SELECT studentName 
INTO @sn 
FROM student
WHERE studentId = 1;
```

so I can use @sn for other query adding it to the previous one. like this

```
SELECT studentName 
INTO @sn 
FROM student
WHERE studentId = 1;

SELECT studentSubject
FROM subject
WHERE subjectStudentName = @sn;
```

The code above works perfectly when I code in my database but it doesn't work when I use PDO in my PHP backend project.
Note: tables and others are just to exemplify the situation, the real intention is to focus on @sn or in general @local_variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be moving data back-and-forth for this purpose.  You should be using `JOIN`s and parameters:

```
SELECT s.studentSubject
FROM subject s JOIN
     student st
     ON st.subjectStudentName = s.studentName
WHERE studentId = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you said there may be many different ways to address the problem, but what I want to know is why @localvariables don't work in PDO sql statements